# How to recover my second partitition on my Hard Drive because the installation of Linux failed due to some disk error.

Tags: partitioning, restore

The drive is not displayed anymore. Is there any way to restore it? I would prefer it to be restored back to windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Obviously, a more detailed question would get a better, more detailed answer.

Asuming, from your title, that you have a working Windows on a single hard-drive and a non-recognised partition, the easiest way is to boot up from the Ubuntu startup disk, find the terminal in the menu & start it, and type:

```
sudo -i
fdisk /dev/sda
t
2
b
w
mkfs -t vfat /dev/sda2
reboot
```

& you should have a working Drive D: - unless there is something you didn't tell us..

I might be a little concerned by the disk error, was it the HDD or CD?